# how to register .edu domain

Tags: dns

How to register .edu domain ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wikipedia article on .edu:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.edu)

> Starting on October 29, 2001, only post-secondary institutions and organizations that are accredited by an agency on the U.S. Department of Education's list of nationally recognized accrediting agencies are eligible to apply for a edu  domain.[3]  Most such agencies accredit only US institutions, so very few non-US institutions qualify, and edu remains almost exclusively a top-level domain of the United States.

More (and official) info in [educause's FAQ](http://net.educause.edu/edudomain/show_faq.asp?code=EDUELIGIBILITY) (they are the central registration agency). You would have to contact them to get any binding information. However, you'll have to represent an educational institution of some sort to even have a chance to be listened to.

Comment: U.S. only... And they would love to sell the shit-marketing that "The Internet is global and equal".

Answer (score 1):

I think that .edu domains are managed by EDUCAUSE, look [here](http://net.educause.edu/edudomain/) for more information.